# Universal property of blowing up in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

I always found Chapter II, Proposition 7.14 very intuitionless. The statement is correct and I understand the proof but it leaves me blind. Can anyone translate its hypotheses to the standard notion for varieties? That is, if I have three varieties $X,Y,Z$ over an algebraically closed field $K$ and I blow up $X$ along the rational map $h : X \to Y$ to obtain $\tilde X$, what is the condition that this result gives me for a morphism $f : Z \to X$ to extend uniquely to a morphism $g : Z \to \tilde X$? I can draw the diagram (involving $f$,$g$ and the graph of $h$), but I am still left clueless.

Comment: I encourage you to read the chapter in Vakil on the blow up (Chapter 22), the proof is essentially immediate once you reduce to the case where $X,Z$ are affine and $I$ is an ideal such whose pullback is globally principal.

Comment: @BenLim : I am not interested in the proof (because I was and I read it). I did have a look at chapter 22 and 23 in Vakil as you said, but it gets very scheme-theoretic (which is fine) and I don't see where I could find the answer to my question. I am interested in the application of this result to varieties and what it means there, i.e. without all the scheme-theoretic language. Is such a translation possible? I am asking because the sheaf $f^{-1}\mathcal I \cdot \mathcal O_Z$ has very little meaning to me in a geometric non-scheme theoretical setting, nor does its invertibility.

Comment: I think the proof of the universal property in Vakil shows that this is something very general that has almost nothing to do with varieties apart from the finite generation of certain ideals. What's wrong scheme theoretic language? I think it makes the proofs very beautiful.

Comment: @BenLim : There is nothing wrong with scheme-theoretic language, but I am explicitly asking for a translation to the language of varieties! Which universal property are you referring to? (Can you quote the numbering of the result?)